# What will happen if I run cron job that is already running in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I would like to know, what will happen If I have one `cron` schedule for every 5 minutes, which updates data in system and it takes about 30 mins to complete its process but if the same `cron` runs again after 5 minutes, will it stop executing already running process and starts from again, leaving half of data not updated?

Any help would be good.

Comment: By default, scheduled tasks will be run even if the previous instance of the task is still running.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam basically, it will not stop previous process right?

Answer (score 1):

use command

[`withoutOverlapping();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps)

> By default, its 24 hours, and you can set `withoutOverlapping(X)`

Comment: I have used it already, I just wanted to know will it stop process if I do not use withoutOverlapping(X)?

Comment: this is to prevent (works like `force` command) not to top running crons. Sure on it